# Filter an array with two comparisions

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am filtering an array using `.filter`, for example:

```
stack_wr = stack_wr.filter(function(obj2) {
    return obj2.class != sec__id;
});
```

The above code works perfectly as I require. My question is can I filter using two comparisons or `return` statements? One with `obj2.class != sec__id` which I have already done and again with `obj2.type != whatever_value` or do I have to filter two times like the way I have done below:

```
stack_wr = stack_wr.filter(function(obj2) {
    return obj2.class != sec__id;
});

stack_wr = stack_wr.filter(function(obj2) {
    return obj2.type != whatever_value;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
stack_wr.filter(function(){
   return this.className !== 'email' && this.type !== 'password';
});
```

[**Simple Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bvmoppdb/)

Comment: yea i thought that would be the answer.... which one will be safe ... your code or `return obj2.class !== sec__id || obj2.type !== whatever_value;`

Comment: @YoYo sorry my bad .. in your case you need to use || instead of &&  .. but let me explain that .. with &&  that mean if the same element has a class and type you defined .. with ||  that mean if the element has any of them

Comment: i checked ... && works same as you explained for || ...i mean it works for distinct element

Comment: and btw || does not work at all ,,,, does not delete even one

Comment: @YoYo yes you are right I tested it here https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bvmoppdb/  .. inside filter && works but || not work .. and && make the same action of || .. thanks to let me know that :)